# Run Dropbox as a service on Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, services, dropbox

I installed the dropbox using the text based install method described [here](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall). However I'd now like dropbox to start automatically when the machine starts up, and start syncing the files. I'll need dropbox to run as the dropbox user, from the dropbox users home directory.

I think the following command will launch dropbox as the dropbox user, in the dropbox users home directory, would you correct me if this doesn't work?

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo -H -u dropbox ./.dropbox-dist/dropbox end script
```

Comment: Doesn't putting this in your crontab, as suggested on the wiki page you referenced, work? `@reboot $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

Comment: I just looked at man 5 crontab, and it seems fedora does support that. I was actually looking at making systemd run the command as a service, but if no one known how to write a systemd startup file, I'll use that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My guesses are:

1. You specified the wrong path to the `dropbox` command; `./` always refers to the current directory, which is *not* changed by using `sudo -H`. You would still have to use `/home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox`.
2. Dropbox is refusing to start because of `end script` in the command line. It is *not* part of the command – the original Upstart example was supposed to be of several lines:

   ```
   start on runlevel 2
   start on runlevel 3
   start on runlevel 4
   start on runlevel 5
   stop on shutdown
   respawn
   script
       # Without next line DB does not sync non ASCII characters (ubuntu 10.04-x86_64, db 0.7.110)
       export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       cd /home/dropbox
       exec sudo -H -u dropbox ./.dropbox-dist/dropbox
   end script
   ```

   As you can see, the Upstart config cd's to `/home/dropbox` before referring to `./.dropbox-dist`.

---

For systemd, create a `/etc/systemd/system/dropbox.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dropbox as a system service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
User=dropbox
# 'LANG' might be unnecessary, since systemd already sets the
# locale for all services according to "/etc/locale.conf".
# Run `systemctl show-environment` to make sure.
Environment=LANG=en_US.utf-8

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Use `systemctl start dropbox.service` to start the service now.

Use `systemctl enable dropbox.service` to make it start automatically at boot.

If you edit the unit file after it has been used once, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to clear the cached-in-memory one.

Comment: Nowadays it seems it's `(...)/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` instead of `(...)/.dropbox-dist/dropbox`. Also this does not give systray icon; probably because this does not run dropbox in the context of user session.